# probema para proxificar archlinux usando wget

Tags: proxy, archlinux, wget

estoy tratando de configurar un proxy en archlinux pero no he podido dar con la solución, luego de configurar las variables `http_proxy` y `https_proxy` me arrojaba el siguiente error:

```
~ sudo pacman -Syu    
:: Synchronizing package databases...
warning: running XferCommand: fork failed!
warning: running XferCommand: fork failed!
warning: running XferCommand: fork failed!
...
warning: running XferCommand: fork failed!
warning: running XferCommand: fork failed!
warning: running XferCommand: fork failed!
error: failed to synchronize all databases (error invoking external downloader)
```

luego instalé `wget`, modifiqué el fichero `/etc/pacman.conf` descomentando la línea siguiente `XferCommand = /usr/bin/wget --passive-ftp -c -O %o %u` tal y como me dice la wiki, y configuré el fichero `/etc/wgetrc` de la siguiente manera que fueron las sugerencias que encontré en internet:

```
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port
use_proxy=on
```

y cuando ejecuto `sudo pacman -Syu` me arroja el siguiente error por cada url de mirror que tengo en mi fichero `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`:

```
--fecha_actual-- url_mirror
Connecting to proxy:port... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

Ejemplo del error con url reales, el proxy no lo describiré, por seguridad sólo pondré `proxy:port`:

```
--2024-03-04 09:52:18-- https://mirror.f4ts.host/archlinux/core/os/x86_64/core.db
Connecting to proxy:port... failed: Network is unreachable.
--2024-03-04 09:52:18-- https://mirror.sunred.org/archlinux/core/os/x86_64/core.db
Connecting to proxy:port... failed: Network is unreachable.
--2024-03-04 09:52:18-- https://archlinux-taller.ws/core/os/x86_64/core.db
Connecting to proxy:port... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

Siguiendo con mi investigación en la red para solucionar el problema me hacen una nueva sugerencia, un usuario que dice que resolvió el problema declarando esto:

```
$ sudo bash
# export http_proxy=someproxy:someport
# pacman -Syu
```

pero yo sigo sin poder conectarme a través del proxy. ¿Cómo podría darle solución al problema?